# Node.js assert.throws with async functions (Promises)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, assert, ecmascript-next

I want to check if an async function throws using [`assert.throws`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message) from the native `assert` module.
I tried with

```
const test = async () => await aPromise();
assert.throws(test); // AssertionError: Missing expected exception..
```

It (obviously?) doesn't work because the function exits before the Promise is resolved.
Yet I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187111/assert-throws-on-asynchronous-method) where the same thing is attained using callbacks.

Any suggestion?

(I'm transpiling to Node.js native generators using Babel.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question is still getting attention, I'd like to sum up the two best solutions, especially to highlight the new standard method.

### Node v10+

There's a dedicated method in the assert library, [`assert.rejects`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message).

### For older versions of Node

A fill from [vitalets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957474/3115520):

```
import assert from 'assert';

async function assertThrowsAsync(fn, regExp) {
  let f = () => {};
  try {
    await fn();
  } catch(e) {
    f = () => {throw e};
  } finally {
    assert.throws(f, regExp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 54):

## node 10 and newer

Since Node.js v10.0, there is [`assert.rejects`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message) which does just that.

## Older versions of node

`async` functions never throw - they return promises that might be rejected.

You cannot use `assert.throws` with them. <s>You need to write your own asynchronous assertion</s>:

```
async function assertThrowsAsynchronously(test, error) {
    try {
        await test();
    } catch(e) {
        if (!error || e instanceof error)
            return "everything is fine";
    }
    throw new AssertionError("Missing rejection" + (error ? " with "+error.name : ""));
}
```

and use it like

```
return assertThrowsAsynchronously(aPromise);
```

in an asynchronous test case.

Comment: This is un-necessary as `assert.throws` already returns a promise which behaves exactly like this

Comment: @Ali Which `assert.throws` are you using? The [native node.js one](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message) neither returns a promise nor copes with a function that returns a promise

Comment: It's the native one. In node v8 at least. It's not documented but that's what it's doing.

Comment: @Ali [No, it doesn't](https://github.com/BridgeAR/node/blob/a5d86f8c4ebf201092a7a155691856e13639f0cb/lib/assert.js#L611)?

Comment: yes it doesn't. Sorry for the confusion. We are using `assert-throws-async` from `npm` and replacing native `assert.throws`. I missed it as the original was replaced in a different file and it worked without having to re-import `assert-throws-async` in my file.

Answer (score 21):

Based on [Bergi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782749/740245) I've suggest more universal solution that utilizes original [assert.throws](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message) for error messages:

```
import assert from 'assert';

async function assertThrowsAsync(fn, regExp) {
  let f = () => {};
  try {
    await fn();
  } catch(e) {
    f = () => {throw e};
  } finally {
    assert.throws(f, regExp);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
it('should throw', async function () {
    await assertThrowsAsync(async () => await asyncTask(), /Error/);
});
```

Comment: excellent solution, hope this makes to the official assert library!

Comment: you're my hero!

Comment: Yeah don't use this in 2018 and beyond, use `assert.rejects()`, here: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message

Answer (score 3):

The answers given work, but I came across this issue today and came up with another solution, that I think is a little simpler.

```
// Code being tested
async function thisFunctionThrows() {
    throw new Error('Bad response')
}


// In your test.
try {
    await thisFunctionThrows()
    assert.equal(1 == 0) // Never gets run. But if it does you know it didn't throw.
} catch (e) {
    assert(e.message.includes('Bad response'))
}
```

Comment: Since I was using an earlier version of Node (< 10) this is the solution I opted for as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use, `assert.rejects()` which is new in Node.js version 10.

At the high level, instead of assert.throws, we want something like assert.rejects, hopefully you can take this and run with it:

```
        const assertRejects = (fn, options) => {
            return Promise.resolve(fn()).catch(e => {
                    return {
                        exception: e,
                        result: 'OK'
                    }
                })
                .then(v => {

                    if (!(v && v.result === 'OK')) {
                        return Promise.reject('Missing exception.');
                    }

                    if (!options) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (options.message) {
                        // check options
                    }

                    console.log('here we check options');

                });
        };

        it('should save with error', async () => {

            // should be an error because of duplication of unique document (see indexes in the model)
            return await assertRejects(async () => {

                patientSubscriber = await PatientSubscriber.create({
                    isSubscribed: true,
                    patient: patient._id,
                    subscriber: user._id
                });

            }, {
                message: /PatientSubscriber validation failed/
            });

        });
```