# assert.throws says => Missing expected exception

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, assert

I am using this chunk of code:

```
       assert.throws(async () => {
            patientSubscriber = await PatientSubscriber.create({
                isSubscribed: true,
                patient: patient._id,
                subscriber: user._id
            });
        },{
             message: /foo/
        });
```

when I run it I get this:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing expected exception.

The assert API is:
https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message

Maybe I am hitting this issue?
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8368

Anyone know what that error is about?

Comment: What's the context for this code? A possible workaround depends on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js assert.throws with async functions (Promises)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782435/node-js-assert-throws-with-async-functions-promises)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error means that there was no exception while it was expected. `async` functions are syntactic sugar for promises. They never throw exceptions but may return rejected promise.

Since the assertion is expected to be synchronous, it's impossible to assert promises this way; the entire callstack should be promise-based.

As it was mentioned in comments, `assert.rejects` appeared in Node 10 and results in rejected promise on assertion fail.

In case promises are handled by a caller (e.g. in most testing frameworks), rejected promise needs to be returned from current function:

```
it('...', async () {
  await assert.rejects((async () => {})()); // current function returns rejected promise
});
```

In case assertion promises aren't handled (e.g. in production), they result in `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` console output, not in exceptions. `unhandledRejection` handler can be set to handle asynchronous errors:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

...

assert.rejects((async () => {})());
```

Comment: yeah, I guess we need to implement `assert.rejects`, instead of `assert.throws`

Comment: I'm sure there are existing attempts on `assert.rejects`, but what's important is what should happen when assertion fails. Since `assert.rejects` doesn't cause an exception itself, it won't make the app to exit. It may cause `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Comment: Seems like there is an assert.rejects since node 10.0. https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Thanks for the information, good to know. My previous comment is applicable to it as well, it's unable to make an assertion to throw like expected, there will be UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning instead. A possible solution would possibly be custom `unhandledRejection` handler or promise-based control flow, `await promise.rejects(...)`.